# Check ajax page update with javascript on a specific url (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome

i'm developing a chrome extension. 
I need to check with javascript if a web page is updated (using Ajax; **without** refresh) and after that get the html code of the element that are changed.

I'll explain:

- I open a specific url with google chrome (extension installed);
- The page loads.
- Then the extension checks if the page changes (the page using ajax; so no refresh) since the page was loaded.
- [optional] If the extension found a modification of page, it saves parts of html code changed in a variable.

I do not know how to do it. Maybe with jquery?
Thanks to those who will help me.
ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: I googled and i discover that i have to use the DOM Mutation Observe but i don't know how to use it on my extension. Anyone give me the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is excellent for the first thee bullets but not for Diffing strings (which is what you are after in bullet four) -- it is probably possible but messy and comparatively slow.

For this I would suggest using some sort of intermediate service (server-side) and Python / PHP / Java or whatever library. You could then make an AJAX call to the server-side service and it could return the data directly to your extension.

The simplest solution to pull in AJAX data in jQuery is to use the `.load()` function (http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Now i have an idea to develop the bullet four, but i have no idea how to develop the script for the first three bullet :D
Any solution?